# How to route to robots.txt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, public, robots.txt

I'm told by various sources that **http://www.anthonygalli.com/robots.txt** does not exist.

I do have a file in **public/robots.txt**

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Sitemap: http://www.anthonygalli.com/sitemap.xml.gz
```

How can I make the route work so that the error goes away and google can properly crawl the site?

Comment: There is no need to have a route defined in the `config/routes.rb` for a `public/robots.txt`, because all files in the `public` should be served directly by the webserver. If the file isn't served by your server than you need to change the servers configuration (not the application). What server do you use? Where do you host your app?

Comment: I host it on heroku @spickermann. I'm using a site to optimize my SEO and it says, "{MISSING:Robots.txt}
The robots.txt file does not exist."

Comment: Do you have the [`rails_12factor`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline#serve-assets) gem installed?

Comment: Yes I do sir @omnikron

Comment: Are there any other files in your public folder? Do they work?

Comment: Yes there are. But they don't work either :/ @omnikron

Comment: Hmm. While I'm asking obvious questions, does it work locally in development?

Comment: Yes it works locally. They're good questions :) @omnikron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that there is the following line in your `config/environment/production.rb`:

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

Comment: Thanks spikermann! When I try to push to heroku tho I get this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'public_file_server' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f4fcbfee2d8>`

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: `Using rails 4.2.0.rc3` sir

Comment: After some intense googling I figured it out. I updated rails then switched `config.eager_load = true` Thanks for leading me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Or just, add the following line to `config/environment/production.rb`:

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```